# Bootstrap 5.3.0 - Navigation bar expanding but not collapsing on index.html

Tags: bootstrap-5, navigationbar, responsive-navigation

I'm trying to make a responsive navigation bar, when I click on the hamburger button the navigation bar expands but clicking on it again doesn't make the navigation bar to collapse. I have searched for the same and tried some solutions but it didn't got fixed.

I'm using bootstrap 5.3.0. When i point to navbar.html, it works fine, but on the index.html it doesn't. I inspected in browser and found that **collapse** changes to **collapse show** upon first click and expands the navbar, on second click it shows **collapsing** and again changes to **collapse show**.

Here's my navbar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" data-bs-theme="dark">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demosite</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand ps-1" href="#">Brand Name</a>
      <button id=collapseButton class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demosite</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="navbar.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h1>Demo Home Page</h1>
      <p>Hello! Welcome to homepage.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
});
```

Comment: If you are injecting the contents of navbar.html into that `#navbar` element then your navbar.html should not contain the `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `head` and `body` elements. Why don't you simply write the navbar HTML in there and try to load it instead?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks, it worked. Can you kindly post this as answer, so i could accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<html>` HTML element represents the root (top-level element) of an HTML document, so it is also referred to as the root element. All other elements must be descendants of this element.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html

The `<body>` HTML element represents the content of an HTML document. There can be only one `<body>` element in a document.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Therefore, if you are loading HTML into an existing HTML document, that loaded HTML must **not** contain these elements as they already exist in your `index.html` document (and would therefore end up as non-permitted children elements within your main `index.html` file).

In short, save your `navbar.html` file with the following contents:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand ps-1" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    <button id=collapseButton class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```